# Most efficient way to insert large amount of data (230M entries) in pyspark table

Tags: python, pyspark, bigdata, grib, pygrib

What is the most efficient way to insert large amounts of data that is generated in a python script?
I am retrieving `.grib` files about weather parameters from several sources. These grib files consist of grid-based data (`1201x2400x80`), which results in a large amount of data.

I have written a script where each value is combined with the corresponding longitude and latitude, resulting in a data structure as follows:

```
+--------------------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
|               value|lat_min|lat_max| lon_min| lon_max|
+--------------------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
|           0.0011200|-90.075|-89.925|-180.075|-179.925|
|           0.0016125|-90.075|-89.925|-179.925|-179.775|
+--------------------+-------+-------+--------+--------+
```

I have tried looping through each of the 80 time steps, and creating a pyspark dataframe, as well as reshaping the whole array into `(230592000,)`, but both methods seem to either take ages to complete or fry the cluster's memory.

I have just discovered Resilient Distributed Dataset's (RDD), and am able to use the map function to create the full 230M entries in RDD format, converting this to a DataFrame or writing it to a file is very slow again.

Is there a way to multithread/distribute/optimize this in a way that is both efficient and doesn't need large amounts of memory?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you able to create a spark dataframe using the grib files? if yes, you can use `unionAll`.

Comment: why can't you keep it a rdd? converting it to a dataframe or writing it to the disk will take memory or space